# Retrieving values of dynamically added forms in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am new to ExtJS and working on application where I have a form(lets call it outerForm). I have buttons to add/remove forms dynamically to/from the **outerForm.**

Now i am using **outerForm.getValues()** to retrieve all the field values(of all the dynamic forms; lets call these forms **innerForm[ ]** ).

> The problem am facing is : even after removing/destroying the form(say
>   **innerForm[k]**), I get its values in the object returned by outerForm.getValues(),although outerForm.items does not have
>   innerForm[k].

I Know i can loop over outerForm.items for retrieving values rather than using outerForm.getValues(), I just want to know the reason of this inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to remove the element from inner form.

```
Ext.getCmp('outerFormId').innerItems[olditem.initialConfig.tabIndex].removeAll();
```

Here i consider outeFormId is a kind of **tab panel** and it contains different tabs so on tab changes,it removes the current inneritem elements,before moving to new one.